# API Authentication - Clients (consumers) vs. local users

Tags: rest, api, authentication, api-design

I work for an ecommerce site and we are looking to expose much of our core functionality via a set of APIs. We plan on re-writing some of our own public facing applications (e.g. the main shop website and our mobile app) to call these new APIs also. We also want to offer some of these APIs out to third-parties who want to integrate with us.

My first question is - what is a suitable authentication method for these APIs? Everything I read is about OAuth, but am I right in saying that this doesn't fit in this case as we're not looking to use another log in system (e.g. Facebook, Google) but rather restrict access to our own API (so maybe an API key or JWT solution would be better?)

Secondly, our current website has it's own user accounts system. How do you offer /user endpoints (like GET user/1235/paymentmethods) in an API like this? Surely the actual user (website customer) needs to authenticate somehow in order for the given API consumer to access their data.

I've spent the last 2 days reading about this but I'm at a loss as to how to go about this! Any help much appreciated.

Comment: OAuth2 works for a bunch of different scenarios, including yours.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - how so? Am I right in thinking the grant type could differentiate between an api client and front end user authenticating?

Comment: The grant_type is certainly a part of it, but it more so has to do with 'who's granting trust to whom'. I would suggest you grab the OAuth2 official specification and read through it. There's examples there and it's a good habit to start from the specs.